# How can I assign a specific role to the people listed as id?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to cast certain members (not all)

I tried it myself but I couldn't.

this is my code:

```
     let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "jail");

     if (!role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, not found.`)

     var list = [524983207943340052, 223550304447234048]


     message.guild.members.cache.filter(list).forEach(member => member.roles.add(role))
     message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**,  ${role} .`)
```

I get this error:

```
(node:4480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fn is not a function
    at Map.filter (C:\Users\user\Desktop\scil bot\scil\rol\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:190:17)
    at Object.run (C:\Users\user\Desktop\scil bot\scil\rol\komutlar\sicil.js:32:34)
    at module.exports.message (C:\Users\user\Desktop\scil bot\scil\rol\node_modules\proton-io\index.js:154:21)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\scil bot\scil\rol\index.js:26:16)
    at Client.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\user\Desktop\scil bot\scil\rol\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\user\Desktop\scil bot\scil\rol\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\scil bot\scil\rol\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\user\Desktop\scil bot\scil\rol\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\user\Desktop\scil bot\scil\rol\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
(node:4480) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4480) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Can you share more code? There is no `fn` in your code you have uploaded here and that is where the problem lies

Comment: i know and i get this error when i run this code i threw

Comment: Yes, but you need to upload more of your code

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so, filters basically work like this: We're basically asking the bot to return for us all of the member objects in a collection who meet a certain condition - Hence why I like to think of it as "Scroll through all of the members and give me back all of the members who x", taking your code, you're basically saying "Scroll through all of the members and give me back all of the members who `id`", which let's be honest makes no sense.

The proper output we'd like is to ask the client to return all of the users who have a certain id, hence why we'll need the use of setting a parameter, let's call it `member`. from there on, we could simply use the `.includes()` function, and determine if the array of IDs includes a certain member's id from the cached members we fetched.

Therefore, your code should instead be looking like the following:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "jail");

 if (!role) return message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**, not found.`)

 var list = [524983207943340052, 223550304447234048]


 message.guild.members.cache.filter(member => list.includes(member.id)).forEach(member => member.roles.add(role))
 message.channel.send(`**${message.author.username}**,  ${role} .`)
```

Comment: Any errors? Try catching the error after adding the role.

Comment: even if i change the role assignment code it does nothing